# Как рекурсивно создавать из массива список?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача: написать в JS функцию которая генерирует из массива список.
Функцию я написал но она работает только на первом уровне вложенности. 
Помогите сделать так чтобы работало не зависимо от количества уровней вложенности. Вот код:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,[4,6,7,9,0],6,7]
var generateList = function(a) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    a.forEach(function (item) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    if(!Array.isArray(item)) {
        li.innerText = item;
    } else {
        var new_ul = document.createElement('ul');
        item.forEach(function(item){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = item;
            new_ul.appendChild(li);
        })
        li.appendChild(new_ul);
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);
})
    return ul;

}
document.body.appendChild(generateList(arr));
```

Comment: Ну так вызывай вместо цикла свою же функцию

Comment: Как это должно работать я понимаю. Да вот только не работает)))

Comment: Можешь в коде написать?

Comment: просто пишешь `var new_ul = generateList(item)` и все

Answer (score 2):

Задача рекурсивна сама по себе: если элемент - массив, то вызвать функцию `generateList`, передав ей этот элемент.

В коде для этого уже сделано половина дела. Нужно заменить цикл прохода по вложенному элементу

```
var new_ul = document.createElement('ul');
item.forEach(function(item){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = item;
    new_ul.appendChild(li);
})
```

На вызов основной функции:

```
var new_ul = generateList(item);
```

Этого уже хватит для решения поставленной задачи.

В дополнение, можно заменить [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) на более подходящий [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), так как в коде происходит ни что иное, как свертка массива в один элемент.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
var arr = [1, [2, [3], 4], 5, [4, [6, 7], 9, 0], 6, 7]
var generateList = function(items) {
  return items.reduce((ul, item) => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      li.innerText = item;
    } else {
      var new_ul = generateList(item);
      li.appendChild(new_ul);
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);
    return ul;
  }, document.createElement('ul'));
}
document.body.appendChild(generateList(arr));
```

---

Вариант без рекурсии: берем из списка элементы, пока не закончатся. Если элемент, число - добавляем li, если массив - добавляем каждый элемент массива в список, сохраняя с ним `ul` в который надо будет все добавлять.

```js
var arr = [1, [2, [3], 4], 5, [4, [6, 7], 9, 0], 6, 7];
var generateList = function(items) {
  var stack = items;
  var root = document.createElement('ul');

  while (stack.length) {
    var item = stack.shift();
    var ul = item.ul || root;
    var value = item.value != null ? item.value : item;
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
      li.innerText = value;
    } else {
      var nestedUl = document.createElement('ul');
      li.appendChild(nestedUl);
      value.reduceRight((stack, el) => {
        stack.unshift({
          value: el,
          ul: nestedUl
        });
        return stack;
      }, stack);

    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  return root;
}
document.body.appendChild(generateList(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1,[[[[['Всё почти получилось']]]]],2,3,4,5,[4,6,7,[4,6,7,9,0,[4,6]],9,0],6,7]
var generateList = function(a, parent) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    a.forEach(item => {
       var li = document.createElement('li');
       if(!Array.isArray(item)) {
         li.innerText = item;
       } else {
         li.appendChild(generateList(item, ul));
       }
       ul.appendChild(li);
    })
    return ul;
}
document.body.appendChild(generateList(arr));
```

Comment: неверно. `generateList` - `ul` возвращает

Comment: @Grundy А в вопросе что требуется?

Comment: А в вопросе не требуется вставлять в ul, что-то кроме `li`, как было у тебя :)

Comment: Код у вас не валидый. У некоторых вложенных элементов `ul`, родительским является не `li`, a `ul`

Comment: @Deonis А почему код от этого не валидный?

Comment: @Grundy Что то не наблюдаю такого..

Comment: @Darth, потому что ты убрал строку `li = generateList(item, ul);` которая как раз и сохраняла в `li` - Элемент `ul` который потом в такой же элемент и `ul` добавлялся.

Comment: Сейчас, после того, как внесли изменения, уже нормально

Comment: @Grundy Нет, я в вопросе не наблюдаю озвученного тобой требования. Ты же вроде не ТС?

Comment: @Darth, в вопросе все работало нормально, а ты сломал поведение, в своем первом варианте решения

Comment: @Grundy У меня всё работало нормально, а ты почему-то решил, что li должен лежать в ul.

Comment: @Darth, `li` должен лежать в `ul` - так написано в спецификации :-)